# Gram-Schmidt process using sagemaths

Tags: python, sage

I'm trying to implement a function myGramSchmidt(L), which takes a list L of vectors living in some inner product space, and returns a new list which has implemented the Gram-Schmidt process above.

My code:

```
def myGramSchmidt(L):

    n = len(L)
    V = L.copy()
    for j in range(n):
        V[j]= V[j]/V[j].norm() #normalised vector
        for i in range(j):
            V[j] -= ip(V[i],V[j]) * V[i] #find value of V[j] which is orthogonal to every previous vectors

    return V
```

Which runs fine (i.e. no syntax error) but doesn't return the desired output. The inner product of two distinct vectors does not return 1. `v.inner_product(w) == 1` is the expected output for all v,w in V.

Comment: How did you determine that the inner product of two distinct vectors does not return 1? Note that your current code does not contain anything called `inner_product` anymore which your question seems to be about.

Comment: Also posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4669496/42781 (now with an answer).